# Importando o Boostrap.sass

Tags: css, bootstrap, sass, npm

Fiz a instalação do Bootstrap SASS no meu projeto pelo NPM. Depois da instalação tentei importar os arquivos do Bootstrap para minha pasta CSS criando um arquivo SASS e dentro dei o comando

```
@import ../bower_components/bootstrap-sass/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap
```

Depois atualizei dando o comando `gulp` no NPM, mas não está importando os arquivos necessários para a pasta.

Estou seguindo os passos desse tutorial exatamente igual 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ITrndc4xFn0&t=1577s

Arquivo *gulpfile.js*:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var sass = require('gulp-ruby-sass');
var watch = require('gulp-watch');

// task para sass
gulp.task('sass', function(){
     return sass('sass/**/*.sass').pipe(gulp.dest('css'))
});


// task para watch
gulp.task('watch', function(){
     gulp.watch('sass/**/*.sass', ['sass'])      
});

// task default 
gulp.task('default', function(){

});

'use strict';

var gulp = require('gulp');
var sass = require('gulp-sass');

gulp.task('sass', function () {
    return gulp.src('sass/**/*.sass')
        .pipe(sass().on('error', sass.logError))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('css'));
});

gulp.task('sass:watch', function () {
    gulp.watch('sass/**/*.sass', ['sass']);
});
```

Comment: Já se certificou se o Bootstrap SASS foi instalado com sucesso? Qual é a saída do comando `gulp`? Você possui o Gulp instalado?

Comment: Sim esta instalado, esta instalado nas dependencias do meu projeto o gulp tambem quando coloco o comando gulp aparece a mensagem:

[15:29:26] Using gulpfile ~\Desktop\Alacarte\gulpfile.js
[15:29:27] Starting 'default'...
[15:29:27] Finished 'default' after 271 μs

Comment: Então edite a pergunta e adicione o conteúdo do arquivo `gulpfile.js`.

Comment: como faço para enviar o arquivo gulpfile

Comment: exede os caracteres

Comment: Poste no ideone.com e cole o link aqui que eu edito a pergunta para você.

Comment: desculpe não consegui usar o indeone nunca usei antes

Comment: criei um link no dropbox com o arquivo https://www.dropbox.com/s/gdcvt1jv102urtt/gulpfile.js?dl=0

Comment: O seu comando `default` está em branco, por isso nada é executado. Talvez seja interessante ler como o `gulp` funciona. Para testar, tente executar o comando `gulp sass`.

Comment: No caso eu colocaria 
gulp.task('default', function(){
gulp.sass

Comment: Testou o comando `gulp sass`? Se me confirmar que funcionou eu respondo com as orientações adequadas.

Comment: funcionou o arquivo plugins foi criado, foi porque eu fiz a chamada errada ? que antes não tinha dado certo ?

Answer (score 1):

O erro está no seu arquivo `gulpfile.js`. Ao executar `gulp`, o comando `default` deste arquivo será executado, porém, no seu caso, ele está em branco, ou seja, nada será feito. Para que outros comandos sejam executados a partir deste, você deve fazer:

```
gulp.task('default', ['sass']);
```

Desta forma, toda vez que o comando `default` for executado, `sass` também será.

Outra coisa que ficou estranha no seu arquivo é a duplicação dos comandos. O comando `sass` foi definido duas vezes e os comandos `watch` e `sass:watch` são os mesmos. Se remover esta redundância, seu arquivo ficará parecido com:

```
'use strict';

var gulp = require('gulp');
var sass = require('gulp-ruby-sass');
var watch = require('gulp-watch');

gulp.task('default', ['sass']);

var gulp = require('gulp');
var sass = require('gulp-sass');

gulp.task('sass', function () {
    return gulp.src('sass/**/*.sass')
        .pipe(sass().on('error', sass.logError))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('css'));
});

gulp.task('sass:watch', function () {
    gulp.watch('sass/**/*.sass', ['sass']);
});
```

Comment: entendi agora, percebi que estava duplicando os arquivos vou arrumalos agora, muito obrigado Anderson pela ajuda e pelo aprendizado realmente preciso praticar mais o gulp.